# How to not show celery results

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Django and Celery for my site.
I have a progress bar. And the problem is that after the process is done Celery displaying the results.
I do not want to show the result.

My Code:

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<style>
  /* Hide the button by default */
  #portfolio-button {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<br>
<br>
<div class='progress-wrapper'>
  <div id='progress-bar' class='progress-bar' style="background-color: #68a9ef; width: 0%;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar-message">Waiting for progress to start...</div>
<script src="{% static 'celery_progress/celery_progress.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var progressUrl = "{% url 'celery_progress:task_status' task_id %}";

  function customResult(resultElement, result) {
<!--    $(resultElement).append($('<h>'));-->
    // Display the button when the progress is done

      $('#portfolio-button').show();

  }

  CeleryProgressBar.initProgressBar(progressUrl, {
    onResult: customResult,
  });
</script>

<p>It may take a few minutes</p>
<form action="/portfolio_analysis_page" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- Give the button an ID for easy access in JavaScript -->
  <button id="portfolio-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Proceed to Portfolio</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

[image: my results]

It should be simple and I tried different solutions but it always showing the dict.

Comment: Did you try removing the following line?
```
    onResult: customResult,
```
Celery sends task result to django backend which sends results to the frontend. If nothing works, just return None inside the celery task or modify the response in django backend.

Comment: In this case, the celery-progress bar does not work.                                      
       ValueError: The view main.views.portfolio_analysis didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
In the task that running the celery, I made returned None instead of the result of the task.

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def porti_portfolio(self, values, user):
    progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
    portfolio = main.run_portfolio(values, user)
    progress_recorder.set_progress(1, 1, "RUNNING")

    # return portfolio.to_json()
    return None
```